# HTML/Javascript Input Issue

Tags: javascript, html

What I'm trying to do is simple. I would like to take the input from an HTML page and use an if statement to select a certain range of numbers. The problem that I'm having is it keeps on outputting "incorrect input".

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/El8ly.png)

[javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBK0v.png)

Comment: Your actual code should be posted **here**, and not as images.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a look at the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) of the site particularly the article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). _Relevant_ code should be added to your question - formatted - as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, on the if condition, change lng and lat to theLng and theLat because they are undefined. Then, to get the value you have to use `.value`, like so :

```
const theLat = document.getElementById('lat').value;
```